# How to use Google Apps Script to Locate Text Between Double Quotes in Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using Google Apps Script to find and format text between double quotes in a Google Docs document.

I have been experimenting with various regex patterns. The patterns work well on websites like regex101, but when implemented in Google Apps Script, they consistently return null. Could someone provide assistance in understanding why this is happening and offer insights on how to make them work within the Apps Script environment?

Your help on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

```
function formatTextBetweenDoubleQuotes() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  
  // Find text between double quotes and format in bold
  var regex = /"([^"]*)"/g;
  var match;
  
  while ((match = body.findText(regex)) !== null) {
    var startOffset = match.getStartOffset();
    var endOffset = match.getEndOffsetInclusive();
    
    // Bold the text between double quotes
    body.setBold(startOffset + 1, endOffset, true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the characters are `"` dec 34 and not `“` dec 147 & 148?  I notice that some times Google Doc changes double quotes to the left and right double quotes (147 & 148) for example `“Hello World”`.

Comment: body does not have a `setBold()` method and the pattern has to be a string try this `"\“([^”]+)\”"`

Answer (score 0):

Finding matching range elements that are in double quotes and set their attributes to bold

```
function formatTextBetweenDoubleQuotes() {
  var bold = {};
  bold[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;//bold attribute
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var match;
  do {
    match = body.findText("\“([^”]+)\”", match);/search pattern must be a string
    if (match) {
      match.getElement().setAttributes(bold);
    }
  } while (match)
}
```

- [body.findText(searchpattern,from)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findtextsearchpattern,-from)
- [Element.setAttributes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element#setattributesattributes)